# Calendar clientViaUserConsent it gives me Authorization Error while creating event

Tags: flutter, mobile, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

clientViaUserConsent opens URL in browser but it said invalid request. this URL is generated internally from lib. I had double-checked my ClientId for both platforms but still face issues for getting AuthClient for create a calendar event.

I used the below packages to create events in the google calender.

googleapis: ^8.1.0

googleapis_auth: ^1.3.0

```
static final androidClientId = ClientId('xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
static final iOSClientId = ClientId('xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');

final _clientID = Platform.isAndroid ? EventProvider.androidClientId : EventProvider.iOSClientId;
final _scopes = [CalendarApi.calendarScope];
clientViaUserConsent(_clientID, _scopes, prompt).then((AuthClient client) {
  var calendar = CalendarApi(client);
}

void prompt(String url) async {
 print("  => $url");
 if (await canLaunch(url)) {
   await launch(URL);
 } else {
   throw 'Could not launch $url';
 }
}
```

I am referring to this article for creating an event in google calendar.

- https://blog.codemagic.io/google-meet-events-in-flutter/
- https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-use-google-calendar-api-adding-the-events-to-calendar-3d8fcb008493

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that error because the app hasn't been verified. If you are the app developer I advise you to check the [App Verification FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) to learn more about the verification steps. If you aren't the developer, you could try to enable the [less secure app access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) but please be mindful of the consequences:

> *Less secure apps can make it easier for hackers to get in to your account, so blocking sign-ins from these apps helps keep your account safe.*